# In react getting 'NaNaNaN.00' while using react-currency-format when the textbox is edited to blank i.e. "" by user

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am using react and needed currency masking for my project. So I used npm package `react-currency-format` i.e. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-currency-format

I used the following code:

```
<NumberFormat
    thousandSeparator=","
    decimalScale={2}
    disabled={this.state.disableAmount}
    fixedDecimalScale
    prefix={currency ? currency.Symbol : ''}
    className="input__field input--small input-skin"
    onValueChange={amount => this.changeAmount(amount)}
    onBlur={this.overSellingWithLimit}
    value={selectedAmount}
/>
```

Initially, it looks good and works fine but when my user enters something and then backspace it to the blank then it gives **NaNaNaN.00**.

Please find the screenshot

[image]

THANKS in advance.

Comment: plz show `changeAmount` fun

Comment: changeAmount is used to get value from the textbox.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the callback functions used, and any utility functions they may be calling, and how you are computing the display value? `changeAmount` would be a great starting candidate to include. It's advisable to always include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example and clear details about issue and reproduction steps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used the same package. Please check the value you are giving to the variable change amount. The package returns number in three formats
{
  formattedValue,
  value,
  floatValue
}

Make sure it's not the formatted value. Sometime in order to take advantage of the format we store the formatted value in state, which later creates not a number issue.

Comment: Yes, I was doing the same. Thanks